# NSTableView crashs when changing data with selected row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

In my cocoa app i have 2 NSTableViews. The AppDelegate is the datasource for both of them. I want to change the data of the second TableView depending on the selected row of the first TableView. For that i use an NSDictionary. I add an array for every entry in the data array of Table1.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView{

    if([table1 selectedRow] != -1 && [[aTableView identifier] isEqualToString:@"table2"]){

    return [[dict objectForKey:[arrForTable1 objectAtIndex:[table1 selectedRow]]] count];
    }

if([[aTableView identifier] isEqualToString:@"table1"]) return [arrForTable1 count];

return 0;
}


- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{

    if([table1 selectedRow] != -1 && [[aTableView identifier] isEqualToString:@"table2"]){

    return [[dict objectForKey:[arrForTable1 objectAtIndex:[table1 selectedRow]]] objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

if([[aTableView identifier] isEqualToString:@"table1"]){

    return [arrForTable1 objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

return nil;
}
```

This code crashes when in table2 a row is selected and after that a switch in the table1 to a row with an empty array.

How can i fix it? I tried to [table2 deselectAll:self] in the - selectionShouldChangeInTableView: method but it doesn't work. It works to trigger the deselectAll: method with an button and that was ok.

Comment: When your program crashes, what is the error in the debugging console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to call `[table2 reloadData]` when your selection in table1 changes.